# Monty Hall (goat) problem w. elementary events

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, games

I am trying to solve the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) with elementary events, but I just can't seem to get it right:

I define four sets:

- Actual door ($R$)
- User's first selected door ($S$)
- Moderator pick ($T$) (moderator always opens a door with a goat)
- User's eventual pick ($U$) (never picks revealed goat)

Each of these sets consists of three elements $R = S = T = U = \{ a, b, c \}$, where $a, b, c$ equal the three possible doors.

My base set of events shall be $O = R~x~S~x~T~x~U$. The event $e = (a,~b,~c,~a)$ for example means the car is behind door $a$, the user first picked door $b$, the moderator then opened $c$, and the user then switched to $a$.

[Here is a link to this model.](http://1drv.ms/1F3Xwmv)

I now define a probability function $P := O \rightarrow [0; 1]$, which assigns 0 to all *impossible* events (e.g., $(a,~a,~a,~a)$, as the moderator cannot open doors the user picked) and $remaining^{-1}$ to all others. In total I have 24 remaining (valid) events and all of them should be (I would argue) equally likely.

With this model I now define some events:

- Winning $W = \{~(r, s, t, u) \in O~|~r = u ~\}$
- Policy 'stay' $P_s = \{~(r, s, t, u) \in O~|~s = u~\}$
- Policy 'change' $P_c = \{~(r, s, t, u) \in O~|~s \neq u~\}$

Lastly, based on these events I would like to compute $P(W~|~P_s)$ as well as $P(W~|~P_c)$.

I would have expected them to turn out as $1/3$ and $2/3$ respectively; however, both of them are $1/2$ (see model link above and change filter for events).

What am I missing? Am I wrong to model the problem with these elementary events? Is assigning all of them the same probability wrong? (I would argue that since every 'step' (R, S, T, U) happens independently in a model with filtered invalid events this should be fair).

**Update**: As @Henry pointed out, my assumption about $T$ being independent is wrong. For example, although in the table $(a, a, c, ?)$ and $(a, b, c, ?)$ have the same number of valid events (2), the probability of $(a, b, c, ?)$ is twice as high (as the moderator is 'forced' into revealing door c in the $(a, b, ?, ?)$ case). $U$ in this case, while technically also dependent, is what one could call *pseudoindependent*, as in every case where I count it it happens to have two cases, evenly distributed.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve the problem in this convoluted way? is it related to some other problem? Or pure didactic?

Comment: my events would have been '1st pick'={car,donkey},'2nd pick'={stay,switch}. stay/swicth result in car or donkey.

Comment: It's purely (self-)educational. Originally I was about to explain working with elementary events to someone else and thought "modeling the Monty Hall problem like this should make it easier to understand (although more lengthy to actually compute)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $3^4=81$ possibilities of which you have filtered out all but $24$.  But these are not equally probable.

What are equally probable are the $3^2=9$ possible combinations of the actual door and the user's first statement.

- In $6$ of the cases they are different and the moderator's door to open is forced: if the user then switches then the user wins while if the user sticks the user loses
- In $3$ of the cases they are the same and the moderator can open either of the other doors: if the user then switches then the user loses while if the user sticks the user wins

Comment: I don't doubt that differing probabilities might be the solution to this problem, but I don't exactly see why yet. Wouldn't it be: Imagine I have randomly picked $(a, a, ?, ?)$, this would leave a total of 4 events: $(a, a, b, a)$, $(a, a, b, c)$, $(a, a, c, a)$ and $(a, a, c, b)$. Wouldn't the moderator's pick be totally random in this case as well (and in the other case $(a, b, ?, ?)$ the moderator's pick were forced to $c$ anyway)?). Lastly for the user's second pick, they are different according to strategy, but wouldn't $P_s$ and $P_c$ filter them out accordingly when computing $P(W|?)$?

Comment: @left4bread: The case of (a,a,?,?) has probability $\frac{1}{9}$.  The moderator can choose $b$ or $c$.  So the case $(a,a,b,?)$ has probability $\frac{1}{18}$ and the case $(a,a,c,?)$ also has probability $\frac{1}{18}$: overall there are $6$ three-state cases with probability $\frac{1}{18}$ and in these the user will lose by switching (the user has a strategy at the end and is not picking at random). So the total probability that the user loses given that the user switches is $\dfrac{6}{18}=\dfrac13$

Comment: ... Meanwhile the case of (a,b,?,?) also has probability $\frac{1}{9}$.  The moderator can only choose $c$.  So the case $(a,b,c,?)$ has probability $\frac{1}{9}$: overall there are $6$ three-state cases with probability $\frac{1}{9}$ and in these the user will win by switching. So the total probability that the user wins given that the user switches is $\dfrac{6}{9}=\dfrac23$

Comment: @left4bread: in summary, a major issue with your counting argument is that you seem to think that $(a,a,c,?)$ is as likely to happen as $(a,b,c,?)$. This is not true

Comment: your last comment was exactly what I missed, thanks! For some reason I believed that each of $R, S, T, U$ would contain the same amount of *information* / randomness, while in reality $T$ does not (i.e., I can't set $P(x)$ for an elementary event $x$ as $P(x_r)~*~P(x_s)~*~...$, but rather I have to do $P(x)~=~P(x_r)~*~P(x_s~|~x_r)~*~P(x_t~|~x_r,x_s)~...$. I updated the table above, and it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's much easier to understand Monty Hall if we think in terms of two possible strategies for the player: "I will stick with my first choice" (STICK) and "I will change doors when offered" (CHANGE). The strategy to be used to play the game has nothing to do with probabilities. The player may decide, in any way he likes, before he plays the game, which strategy he's going to use.

Now, again without talking about probabilities, there are two important facts: under strategy STICK you win if and only if your initial choice is the correct door; and under strategy CHANGE you win the prize if and only if your initial choice is a wrong door.

Hence, if you assign the same probability $1/3$ for the prize to be behind each of the three doors, it follows that under strategy STICK your probability of winning is $1/3$, while under strategy CHANGE your probability of winning the prize is $2/3$. This is why strategy CHANGE is better.

Of course, there is nothing special about the choice of uniform probabilities for the prize being behind each of the three doors. If instead you assign probabilities $a$, $b$, and $c$ (none of which we'll suppose to be equal to $1$), then under strategy STICK you should choose the door with maximum probability, while under strategy CHANGE you should start with the door with the smallest probability. But, again, strategy CHANGE is better because $\max\{a,b,c\}<\max\{1-a,1-b,1-c\}$. Hence, choosing the least probable door and changing when offered to do so is a good way to play the Monty Hall game.

Comment: Thanks. I think for me it's not so much about understanding the Monty Hall problem (I'm totally aware that the probabilities should be $1/3$ and $2/3$ respectively). The more I think about it now is *my* problem is probably why (when modeling it with elementary events) I can't assume the base events to be equally probable if (and only if) I then use the two policies to actually filter out strategies. In other words, imagine each party always rolled dice before taking a decision (yielding my table), and now ex-post I'm asking, *but what if they didn't roll a dice?*

Comment: @left4bread, so my question was around your choice of _elementary events_, actually. Why did you choose these particular ones? You could pick different elementary events, and solve it easier

Comment: @Aksakal, as strange as it may sound, to me it's the most *simple* (not in terms of least work, but in terms of straightforwardness) and natural way of doing it. My thinking was along the lines: Let's model each *random* factor of this game in its own, individual and observable random variable (R, S, T, U), then the rest should more or less mechanically follow. Although I eventually shot myself in the foot, I actually assumed going this way I (or anyone else) would probably end up at the correct result with the least *likelihood* of error ...

Comment: (In other words, this exercise was not so much about the Monty Hall problem, as it was about modeling *real-world problems* and constructing and working with $\Omega$-s and event subsets).